# how to query the user customer in user model to do a query and add record in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a custom user model with a field 'customer'. Each user has a customer. I am trying to get the logged in users customer so that when I add infringer, the correct customer is added for the record.

1. I think below is wrong in views. customer=request.user.customer
2. think below is wrong in forms. customer__user=self.customer

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createInfringer(request):
   customer=request.user.customer
   
   form = InfringerForm(customer=request.customer)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      
      form = InfringerForm(customer, request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         
         form.save()
      return redirect('infringer-list')
   context ={'form': form}
   return render (request, 'base/infringement_form.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class InfringerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, customer, *args, **kwargs):
      self.customer = customer  
      super(InfringerForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(customer__user=self.customer)
    class Meta:
        model = Infringer
        fields = ['name', 'brand_name','status' , 'customer']
```

models.py

```
class Infringer (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, default='@cudo.ai')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name='player', blank=True) 
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(AbstractUser):


email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, default="logo.svg")
username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=False, 
default='')
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
```

Comment: getting close... Issues with the forms.py now. self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(customer=customer) "Cannot resolve keyword 'customer' into field" I want to only show the customers in the drop down associated with the logged in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you identified the problems correctly.
So I think you need to:

1. Change line 5 in views.py: `form = InfringerForm(customer=customer)`
2. Change line 5 in form.py" `self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(customer=customer)`

Comment: Getting closer but I have an issue with this self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(customer=customer) "Cannot resolve keyword 'customer' into field"

Answer (score 1):

1. views.py
   customer=request.user.customer
   form = InfringerForm(customer=customer)
2. forms.py
   self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(name=customer)

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I'm curious as to why you even needed `forms.py self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(name=customer)`.   Or why you needed to override the ModeForm.  It should be automatically done by a ModelForm. No need to respond.  I was just curious.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am new to django. I supposed I added this so only the correct customers are listed in the drop down.  But I guess I don't even need that, if It auto saves the customer.